# Where can I view tools or packages availble in Homebrew

Tags: macports, homebrew

I am trying homebrew for the first time. I used to use macports. 
In macports, it is quick clear which ports are available, and their versions (http://www.macports.org/ports.php).

Is there any such website / tools in hombrew?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [browse the Formula directory on GitHub](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula/). Or type `brew search`.
There is even a website [braumeister.org](http://braumeister.org).

Comment: does homebrew have the latest version, or can you change between the version. For example, looks like brew search ruby installs ruby 1.9.3. Can I install ruby 1.9.2 for example?

Comment: The formula directory is a git repository so yeah you will be able to do that. Try `brew versions ruby`. Check out this question on Stack Overflow for more informations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: brew versions ruby doesnt work. I get:
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Would I have to download the git repository? if so, which one is it? the hombrew/libary simply has a list of .rb files ...

Answer (score 0):

Following Jerome Mahuet's answer, I could not find how to locate various versions of a particular formula.

here is what my problem was:

- I installed homebrew as instructed on the website
- This installed the very basics of homebrew, but did not install the .git repository folder
- As a result, brew versions ruby did not work
- to fix this, simply type brew update

You can then view the versions via

```
brew versions ruby
```

Comment: I've fixed this in mxcl/master now.